# how to set a Title in the middle of the toolbar in Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android

A very little bit problem i will be thankful to you if you will help me, i am working on a calendar app n the main screen i have a navigation drawer and i am trying to set a title(Menu) in the middle of the toolbar by using some properties but it does not set it exactly in the middle. In the case of navigation drawer toolbar does not take full width of screen, it does not consider the space taking by navigation_View.

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#3256e1"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">
        <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="MENUE"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/wallet"
                    />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Toolbar has left margin = 16dp, you can set padding right for text view --> Your text will be in center of toolbar

Comment: thank you so much for reply.Dear it's working well on my device but when i run this app n another device with high resolution then padding creating problem but on my device it's working perfectly. is there any solution for that ?

Comment: Try this: Toolbar parent =(Toolbar) customView.getParent();
parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0,0);

Comment: it gets error at ".customView.."  can't resolve this symbol. what will be there?

Comment: mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (mToolbar != null) {
            mToolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0,0);
            setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
        }